# Performance counter instances spanning different performance counters

Tags: c#, performancecounter

What I am seeing is that my performance counter instances are being added to other counters within the performance category beyond the counter specified.

[image]

Given the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication26
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string category = "Foo";
            string categoryHelp = "Test counters";
            string fooCounter1Name = "Test Foo counter 1";
            string fooCounter1InstanceName = fooCounter1Name + "Instance";
            string fooCounter2Name = "Test Foo counter 2";
            string fooCounter2InstanceName = fooCounter2Name + "Instance";

            if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(category))
                PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(category);

            var counterCreationDataCollection = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
            counterCreationDataCollection.Add(new CounterCreationData(fooCounter1Name, "", PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond64));
            counterCreationDataCollection.Add(new CounterCreationData(fooCounter2Name, "", PerformanceCounterType.RateOfCountsPerSecond64));

            PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(category, categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, counterCreationDataCollection);

            PerformanceCounter fooCounter1Instance = new PerformanceCounter();
            fooCounter1Instance.CategoryName = category;
            fooCounter1Instance.CounterName = fooCounter1Name;
            fooCounter1Instance.InstanceName = fooCounter1InstanceName;
            fooCounter1Instance.InstanceLifetime = PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime.Process;
            fooCounter1Instance.ReadOnly = false;

            PerformanceCounter fooCounter2Instance = new PerformanceCounter();
            fooCounter2Instance.CategoryName = category;
            fooCounter2Instance.CounterName = fooCounter2Name;
            fooCounter2Instance.InstanceName = fooCounter2InstanceName;
            fooCounter2Instance.InstanceLifetime = PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime.Process;
            fooCounter2Instance.ReadOnly = false;

            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    fooCounter1Instance.Increment();
                    fooCounter2Instance.Increment();
                    SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 500);
                }
            }, cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            task.Wait(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Why do the instances show in both counters?

From PerfMon:

[image]

I would expect the instance (fooCounter1InstanceName) to only be shown under "Test Foo counter 1" counter but it is listed under "Test Foo counter 2" as well. More interesting is that the instance is available to select in PerfMon but values are only written to the instance under the correct counter name, e.g. fooCounter1InstanceName in "Test Foo counter 1" counter and fooCounter2InstanceName in "Test Foo counter 2" counter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found my own answer. From the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.instancename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In some situations, categories are subdivided into instances, which
>   track data about multiple occurrences of the object that a category
>   relates to. **Instances apply to the category as whole, rather than to
>   individual counters.** Every counter within a category has each instance
>   defined for the category. For example, the Process category contains
>   instances named Idle and System. Every counter within the Process
>   category thus contains data for each instance, showing information
>   about either idle processes or system processes.

The implication of this is that I should define counters such as "# messages read per second" and "# messages sent per second" and then an instance is created for the category and under each counter would be a "view" into that instance which may or may not be written to.

This seems counter intuitive (pun intended) as some counters won't have values written to it so why list the instance under that counter and why specify an instance name when setting up the counter instance but give the user of performance monitor the impression that a counter applies to the instance when it won't?

Comment: counter intuitive. priceless. you sir are a master wordsmith.

Comment: This is not a fail, indeed completely makes sense. If you have a multiinstance category like "Queues", and have say counter Length, AddsPersSecond, etc, then you add instance QueueA and QueueB it is clear that you want those instances under all counters in this category